# How to simplify this Rails helper function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I made this helper function in my `application_helper.rb` file:

```
def link_to_related(path)
  link_to "Show", path 
end
```

So I can use it in my forms like this:

```
<%= link_to_related(person_path(f.object.person)) %>
```

Is there a way to further simplify this so I can just say:

```
<%= link_to_related(:person) %>
```

I've been trying to get my head around this, but to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you're only linking to a show action then you don't need to supply a path, just the object. For example `link_to "Show", @person`

Comment: Ah yes, excellent. Thanks. This is what I do now: `<%= link_to_related(f.object.person) %>`

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only using this helper to link to `show` actions, you don't need to specify the path, passing in the object should be enough:

```
def link_to_related(object)
  link_to "Show", object 
end

<%= link_to_related f.object.person %>
```

Although that's about as long as typing `link_to "Show", f.object.person` :)